# using Jar file in java code

Tags: java, jar, include-path

I am coding in simple text document and executing java code with command line with javac command. i want to use jar file which is in directory like /abc/public/assi1 and i have code which is in directory like /abc/assi1. I am including the jar file with import statement in the class myClass.java which is in directory /abc/assi1/myClass.java i am getting errors.

It is not recognizing the things which are in the jar file.

Could some one please help in this.

Thanks

Comment: Use a proper IDE and all your problems might be magically solved.

Comment: If you really insist in using it like that, you need to add your custom `.jar` to both compile and runtime classpath...

Answer (score 4):

You can compile your code like this from the directory /abc/assi1:

```
 javac -cp .:/abc/public/assi1/your.jar -d . your-java-class.java
```

Then you can run your code like this from the directory /abc/assi1:

```
 java -cp .:/abc/public/assi1/your.jar your-java-class
```

`-cp` option sets the class path for you on command line. It adds the required jar file and the current directory `.` into your class path.

Answer (score 2):

The jar has to be inside your java path.

You have to write something like this.

```
javac -classpath \path\to\lib.jar src.java
```

Comment: and also the anwser from anubhava for runtime, mine is only for the compiler.